# Passing object from JSP to spring controller

Tags: spring, jsp

I have the below table in a .JSP page:

```
<form:form method="post" action="update.dtt" id="contactForms" modelAttribute="contactForms" >
<c:forEach items="${pList}" var="cf">
<tr>
<td align="center"><c:out value="${cf.fname}" /></td>
<td align="center"><c:out value="${cf.lname}" /></td>
<td align="center"><c:out value="${cf.cprovider}" /></td>
<td align="center"><c:out value="${cf.id}" /></td>
<td align="center"><c:out value="${cf.phone}" /></td>
<td><input type="submit" value="Update Contact"/></td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
</form:form>
```

I'm iterating over the list (this is list of objects) and adding an Update Contact button for each record in the list. How can I pass on the particular instance (object) to the controller when the Update button is clicked?

The controller I have is as below. However I'm getting null.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/update.dtt", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String updateView(@ModelAttribute("contactForms") Banks bank,      HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Model model) {

    System.out.println("*First Name*" + bank.getFname());
//......

    return "detailBank"; //name of jsp file
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to have a hidden form field for each information you want to send to the server.

Since you have one button for each row, you should also have one form for each row. So the `<form:form>` and `</form:form>` lines should be inside the `<c:forEach>`, and not outside.

Comment: I had tried having <form:form><form:form> inside the for loop. Still it was returning Null.

Comment: You don't have any form field in your form. You need to add hidden fields in the form. I told you that in my answer. How do you expect Spring to guess what the contact is if you don't send anything?

Comment: Got it thank you. What if I had not made use of <form> and had links i.e. <a href> instead of buttons?

Comment: You would have had to pass parameters in the query string: <c:url value="/user/update.dtt" var="updateContactUrl"><c:param name="id" value="${cf.id}"/></c:url> ... <a href="${fn:escapeXml(updateContactUrl)}">Update</a>

Comment: ok. the goal i am trying to achieve is when the user clicks on the update button a new page opens up with pre-populated existing data in the text boxes. According to the solution which is you said above. I will need to pass all the 5 variables in order to populate the text boxes.Isn't there any other way in which I can directly send the entire object instead of individual variables?

Comment: I had achieved the same thing using JSF (as shown below)
     <h:column>
              <f:facet name="header">
                   <h:outputText value="First Name"/>
              </f:facet>
             <h:commandLink value="#{bk.fname}" action="#{bankController.getDetailRecord(bk)}"/>
                </h:column>

Where bk is the object inside a List and had used datatable. 
Wanted to achieve something similar using spring

Comment: The object should be in your database. Sending its ID should be sufficient. Just fetch the object from the DB using its ID and prepopulate the form with the data in the object.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. That's how I am doing it now. However wanted to eliminate connecting to the DB for pre-populating the text boxes.
Isn't there anything similar in Spring (as in JSF explained above) where I can pass the entire object to the controller.

Comment: You could include a hidden field for every text box, or put the whole list into the HttpSession. But the more stateless the application is, the more simple and scalable it is. Accessing the DB by primary key is very fast.

Answer (score 0):

You need reference the instance by position, accessing to the element of the list by position.

```
list[i].name
list[i].surname
```

where list is the element in your pojo.

Comment: this does not provide a solution to the original question at all.